# CRUD con MVC y POO en Java y MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, mvc, poo

Tengo la siguiente situación en el proyecto que estoy trabajando, cuando paso los datos de un Jtable a un formulario y deseo modificar los datos, al momento de cambiar la información y por siguiente de presionar el botón EDITAR los datos no se modifican, aquí anexo los fragmentos de código en el primero se muestra la consulta sql para actualizar y el segundo fragmento de código es parte de mi controlador donde le mando las acciones al botón EDITAR, agrego que cuando presiono el botón EDITAR me aparece el mensaje "SURGIO UN ERROR AL ACTUALIZAR":

```
//Fragmento de codigo de mi paquete Modelo  
//Metodo actualizar
    @Override
    public void actualizar(Object objeto) throws Exception {
        ModeloProducto producto = (ModeloProducto) objeto;

        try{

            // Abrir conexion
            this.connect();

            String sql = "UPDATE productos SET nombre = ?, codigo = ?, descripcion = ?, precio = ?, stock = ?, status = ? WHERE idProducto = idProducto;";

            this.sqlConsulta = this.conexion.prepareStatement(sql);

            this.sqlConsulta.setInt(1, producto.getId());
            this.sqlConsulta.setString(2, producto.getNombre());
            this.sqlConsulta.setString(3, producto.getCodigo());
            this.sqlConsulta.setString(4, producto.getDescripcion());
            this.sqlConsulta.setFloat(5, producto.getPrecio());
            this.sqlConsulta.setInt(6, producto.getStock());
            this.sqlConsulta.setInt(7, 1);

            // Executa consulta y Cerrar conexion
            this.sqlConsulta.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println("SURGIO UN ERROR AL ACTUALIZAR");
        }
        this.desconectar();
    }

//Fragemento de codigo de mi paquete controlador ACCIONES DE LOS BOTONES
if (e.getSource() == this.forminventario.btnEditar) {
            try {

                producto.setId(Integer.parseInt(forminventario.txtId.getText()));
                producto.setCodigo(forminventario.txtCodigo.getText());
                producto.setNombre(forminventario.txtNombre.getText());
                producto.setDescripcion(forminventario.txtDescripcion.getText());
                producto.setPrecio(Float.parseFloat(forminventario.txtPrecio.getText()));
                producto.setStock(Integer.parseInt(forminventario.txtStock.getText()));

                dbproducto.actualizar(producto);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(forminventario, "¡REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO!");
                clean();
                this.cargarTabla("");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ControladorProducto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Hola, coloca tu excepción al final  para ver dónde ocurre.

Comment: La excepción que capturas contiene mucha información sobre el error específico que está pasando. Un *e.getMessage()* o mejor un *e.printStackTrace()* dará mucha más información para identificar el problema. Incorpora esa información a tu pregunta.

Comment: En primer término tu consulta es errónea: `UPDATE productos SET ... WHERE idProducto = idProducto`, ¿a qué equivale ahí `idProducto` como criterio?, es evidente que lo que hace falta ahí es un marcador de posición `?`, de hecho, estás seteando un parámetro `7` aquí `this.sqlConsulta.setInt(7, 1);` (no es que sea demasiado práctico tu código, pues ¿siempre quieres actualizar el producto con id 1?). Sea como sea, la consulta debería funcionar si la escribes así: **`UPDATE productos SET nombre = ?, codigo = ?, descripcion = ?, precio = ?, stock = ?, status = ? WHERE idProducto = ?`**